# Windows 10 virtual machine disappears in seamless mode in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, gnu

I have Arch Linux (64-bit) and I installed 32-bit Windows 10 in VirtualBox. Everything seems to work fine—fullscreen, scaled, etc…—except for seamless mode. When I activate seamless mode, the virtual machine disappears. It continues to run, but it just disappears. How can I fix this?

(And, yes, I have guest additions installed.)

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that what seamless mode does?  I guess, what are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: Well, I am expecting a fullscreen 1920x1080 windows desktop, but it looks like there is just a chunk of a corner and a windows taskbar at the bottom that disappears when I click it

Comment: Seamless mode just does not work yet
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15092

Comment: Google brought me here. I'm running an Ubuntu guest on a Windows 10 host. I'm expecting to see the normal Windows screen, with the Ubuntu toolbar/dock as well as the "Activities" bar with the date, shut-off options, etc. When I switch to seamless, anything but guest windows I had open disappears. That means I can't start any  new programs in seamless mode.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [known Virtualbox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15092) for this behavior which is nearly 2 years since it was reported.

If you want to fix it, I guess you would need to submit a pull requets with a fix to Virtualbox's team... or sadly, wait longer :/

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox's Seamless Mode doesn't show a seamless desktop.  If you have any applications running on your VM, seamless mode makes the VM desktop disappear and puts the VM applications on your desktop, so you can use, for example, Google Chrome for Windows on a Linux desktop.  See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/171145/use-virtualboxs-seamless-mode-or-vmwares-unity-mode-to-seamlessly-run-programs-from-a-virtual-machine/) for more information.