# VirtualBox: menu / task bar not visibile in seamless mode

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I have the following setup:

- Host: Windows 10
- Guest: CentOS 7
- VirtualBox: 5.2.18

With the latest guest additions installed I can enable seamless mode for the virtualized CentOS but that hides the menu bar (with the buttons *Applications*, *Places*, etc.) as well as the task bar with the open applications. How can I enable them in CentOS 7 to work with seamless mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 virtual machine disappears in seamless mode in Arch Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/899368/windows-10-virtual-machine-disappears-in-seamless-mode-in-arch-linux)

Comment: I don't see the connection to this one... I've seen and worked with a virtualized RedHat with the bars visible in seamless mode for the last two years but I don't know how to enable it with CentOS.